# Why I got "-bash: hadoop: command not found" warning when open a new terminal window in Mac OS?

Tags: macos, hadoop

After I installed hadoop in my MacOS, I found there is always a warning "-bash: hadoop: command not found" displayed when I open a new terminal window every time. What's wrong? and How can I fix it? Thanks.

```
Last login: Fri Jan  8 20:13:00 on ttys010
-bash: hadoop: command not found
SJ-DN0393:github admin$
```

Here is the content of my /etc/profile file:

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
    [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi

export GITLAB_HOME=/Users/admin/dev/gitlab
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/lib"
export BASH_SILENCE_DEPRECATION_WARNING=1
export ZEPPELIN_HOME=/Users/admin/dev/zeppelin-0.9.0-preview2-bin-all
export SPARK_HOME=/Users/admin/dev/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7
export ZOOKEEPER_HOME=/Users/admin/dev/apache-zookeeper-3.6.2-bin
export CONFLUENT_HOME=/Users/admin/dev/confluent-6.0.1
export HADOOP_HOME=/Users/admin/dev/hadoop-2.8.5
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`hadoop classpath`
export FLINK_HOME=/Users/admin/dev/flink-1.12.0
export FLINK_CONF_DIR=$FLINK_HOME/conf
export FLINK_OPT_DIR=$FLINK_HOME/opt
export FLINK_PLUGINS_DIR=$FLINK_HOME/plugins
export FLINK_BIN_DIR=$FLINK_HOME/bin
export FLINK_LIB_DIR=$FLINK_HOME/lib
export MYSQL_HOME=/usr/local/mysql-5.7.31-macos10.14-x86_64
export HIVE_HOME=/Users/admin/dev/apache-hive-2.3.7-bin
export HBASE_HOME=/Users/admin/dev/hbase-2.2.6
export KAFKA_HOME=/Users/admin/dev/kafka_2.12-2.4.1
export JAVA_HOME=/Users/admin/.sdkman/candidates/java/current
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JRE_HOME/lib:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-aliyun-3.3.0.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.8.5.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.8.5.jar
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin:/usr/local/opt/redis@4.0/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$PATH:$FLINK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$MYSQL_HOME/bin:$ZEPPELIN_HOME/bin:$ZOOKEEPER_HOME/bin:$HBASE_HOME/bin:$KAFKA_HOME/bin:$CONFLUENT_HOME/bin:$HIVE_HOME/bin
```

Comment: Why do you have separate folders for Kafka, Zookeeper, and Confluent, when Confluent contains both Kafka and Zookeeper?

Answer (score 0):

You have `` `hadoop classpath` `` being invoked when you open the shell.

Since `hadoop` is not in the PATH until the very end of sourcing this file, the command wouldnt be found

The appropriate solution could be use `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop classpath`